# Image is not shown in ReactJS / NextJS / Tailwind UI

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

i am trying to replace the image which has this source: "https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"

When I try to replace it with a local image from my directory, then it only shows some kind of default image.

Anyone knows why?

I copied a component from Tailwind UI which is this:

````
import { LockClosedIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <>
      {/*
        This example requires updating your template:

        ```
        <html class="h-full bg-gray-50">
        <body class="h-full">
        ```
      */}
      <div className="min-h-full flex items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
          <div>
            <img
              className="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
              src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
              alt="Workflow"
            />
            <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl tracking-tight font-bold text-gray-900">
              Sign in to your account
            </h2>
            <p className="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-600">
              Or{' '}
              <a href="#" className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                start your 14-day free trial
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="remember" defaultValue="true" />
            <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="email-address" className="sr-only">
                  Email address
                </label>
                <input
                  id="email-address"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  required
                  className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Email address"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  required
                  className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <input
                  id="remember-me"
                  name="remember-me"
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
                />
                <label htmlFor="remember-me" className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900">
                  Remember me
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="text-sm">
                <a href="#" className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                  Forgot your password?
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
              >
                <span className="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                  <LockClosedIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                </span>
                Sign in
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
````

Comment: Which default image is shown and what is the path you're trying to use instead of the image above? Also, what is the image you're trying to use? Is it in `.svg`?

Comment: Hi ChenBr - thank your for your help! 
I am trying to display a .png but I also tried it with a .jpg ... 
It is displaying some kind of small document pic - I guess it is some default image - you can try it if you leave src="" empty. 
The weird thing is: when I try this here: 

<img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="Wild Landscape" />

... then it works ... ??? how?

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHi0n.jpg)

this is the default picture being shown (the small pic - not the landscape)

here's the code:

````
import { LockClosedIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import fhws from '../../../public/media/fhws.png'

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <>
      {/*
        This example requires updating your template:

        ```
        <html class="h-full bg-gray-50">
        <body class="h-full">
        ```
      */}
      <div className="min-h-full flex items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
          <div>
            <img
              className="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
              src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
              alt="Workflow"
            />
          <img src={fhws} class="img-fluid" alt="Wild Landscape" />
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="Wild Landscape" />
````